# How do we add a second website publication to our Tridion environment?

Tags: configuration, deployer

We would like to add a second website Publication to our SDL Tridion 2013 environment. This is on Windows 2008.

At the moment we have one website (www.website1.com) that is defined in IIS 7.5 (Webname: “Live”). The root-path for this is `f:\presentation\..`

We would like to add another website (www.website2.com) that is now defined also in the IIS as a different web “website2” with also a different IP-address. The path for this web is `e:\website2\..`

Is there a preferred solution for this?
Maybe a second Deployer or something other?

How do we configure this inside the `cd_storage_conf.xml`?

The publishing process should use the FTP-protocol (FTP preferred), maybe here we need a second Publication Target. Right?

Please inform us with some details, how we can have the best solution for us.
If you need more details about our system, please ask. I will provide missing details.

Comment: When you say "with also a different IP-address", does this mean that the new website is on a different server, or just that it is on a different port/hostname?

Answer (score 3):

As you two websites are on different drives (E and F), but on the same server (presumably), you can do this by having Publication specific settings within your `cd_storage_conf.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration Version="6.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
  <Global>
    ...
    <Storages TempFileSystemTransactionLocation="F:\Temp" >    
      ...
      <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Type="filesystem" Id="IISFileSystem" defaultStorage="false" defaultFilesystem="false">
        <Root Path="F:\" />
      </Storage>

      <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="Website2_IISFileSystem" defaultFilesystem="false">
        <Root Path="E:\website2" />
      </Storage>
    </Storages>
  </Global>

  <ItemTypes cached="true" defaultStorageId="sqlServer">
    <Item cached="true" storageId="IISFileSystem" typeMapping="Page" />
    <Item cached="true" storageId="IISFileSystem" typeMapping="Binary" />

    <!-- Website 2 Publication specific -->
    <Publication Id="99" defaultStorageId="sqlServer" cached="true">
      <Item cached="true" storageId="Website2_IISFileSystem" typeMapping="Page" />
      <Item cached="true" storageId="Website2_IISFileSystem" typeMapping="Binary" />
      <!-- any other item mappings you need -->
    </Publication>
  </ItemTypes>
</Configuration>
```

You will not need another Deployer (or Publishing Target) this way.

(*Obviously you will need to merge the Publication specific settings in to your own `cd_storage_conf.xml` file, as you will possibly have other configuration items in there.)

Answer (score 1):

if new site has to be deployed on different Physical Server, then can have another PublicationTarget or also use shared network approach as mentioned in first comment below.

if your new website has to be on same server but existing site is on different protocol other than FTP  (as you want to use FTP) you need different PubTarget.

if same server then follow Johathan's answer, also add your new publication to existing Publication Target.

Comment: Hey Raj. I'm not sure I agree with your first point. If the new site has to be on a different web server, then it's possible to do this with a single Deployer, as long as the Deployer has access to both web servers (using shared network folders or similar).

Comment: Yes @JonathanWilliams, that's also an option, but condition, server should be on same network, security & performance stuff. thanks for update.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my delay and many thanks for your help/suggestion, i will check this.

Maybe i will come back to you with a changed configuration and you can check this?
So, i will safe if some specialist like you look over it... :)

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
 Bjoern Dieck

Comment: Hi Bjoern, I'm glad you are getting somewhere with your problem. However, this is not an answer to your question. Did you intend to comment on another answer instead? It's unclear which answer you intended to comment on for me to move it. For more information about how this site works see the tour  http://tridion.stackexchange.com/tour and the help centre http://tridion.stackexchange.com/help. Please could you delete this answer and add a comment to the answer you intended.